# Change default grace period for Karaf bundle

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf

I need to change the default 5 minute grace period for my bundle. It can be done in the manifest file adding blueprint.timeout parameter but the file is an autogenerated file so I can't change it each time manually.

In my pom.xml I use maven-bundle-plugin. Is it possible to change the grace period using maven-bundle-plugin?

Is it possible to change default grace period globally, not for a single bundle?

Comment: The following configuration needs to be added to pom.xml for maven-bundle-plugin:
`
     <configuration>
      <instructions>
       <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId};blueprint.graceperiod:=true;blueprint.timeout:=600000</Bundle-SymbolicName>
      </instructions>
     </configuration>
`